# Blog portal with http redirects

Tags: php, html, ajax

am creating a blog portal website where user "abc" registeres user_id, username, email, password in user_table etc. and then page like  Facebook "xyz" will be created in page_id, user_id, page_name in  page_table. User abc is admin.
My question is when outside user visits the website or click on link (e.g
https://www.example.com/xyz, 
)the page of "xyz" will be opened like Facebook (e.g https://www.facebook.com/cocacola
How can i do this using .htacces in php?

Comment: Is it friendly url's you're asking about?

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/cocacola simple when u click on cocacola link then the page of cocacola will be open!! not index page.when user https://www.facebook.com/ go to this link without username then index page will be open!!

Comment: Nah, I guess he wants people that are not logged in to redirect to his facebook-page.

Comment: Please try to revise your post - for example to contain a question.

Comment: Are you asking how to do the redirect, or how to do all of it? For the redirect, use `header('Location: https://www.facebook.com/whatever'); exit();` - and for the latter, well, that question is a bit broad for a question here! `:)`

Comment: You'll need to have a login system, and sessions so you can determine whether a user is logged in, and if so, what its user id is. How much code have you got working so far?

Comment: Whats up will all the editing of your post man!?

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a wild guess and say that what you want to use is mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z]+)/$ index.php?user=$1
```

that would rewrite the address www.example.com/index.php?user=ABC to www.example.com/user/ABC

Comment: any script or tutorial about this??

Comment: Yes just google mod_rewrite tutorial and you'll be all set. There's tons of them!